# Select multiple columns to excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub ShowHideWST_Click()
Dim MyC As String
MyC = "G:I" And "T:W"
If ShowHideWST.Value Then
Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(MyC).Hidden = True
Else
Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(MyC).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

I want to select multiple column in excel VBA. **MyC = "G:I And "T:W"** is clearly giving error. Please guide me how to select multiple columns

Comment: you probably want a `Range`

Comment: You can easily Record a Macro to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, access the range first (Provide the range in`A1`-style, try doing the action with the macro recorder and it would have shown you the range reference) then to its `Columns` property to set the `Hidden` property, the code can be shorten as well since you are setting the `Hidden` value to be the same as `ShowHideWST.Value`:

```
Private Sub ShowHideWST_Click()
    Const MyC As String = "G:I,T:W"
    
    ActiveSheet.Range(MyC).Columns.Hidden = ShowHideWST.Value
End Sub
```